# Stream Analytics - Processing JSON with no array name

Tags: azure, azure-stream-analytics, streaming-analytics

IoT Edge v2 with the modbus module sends data to IoT Hub in the format of:

```
[
{
    "DisplayName": "Voltage",
    "HwId": "",
    "Address": "400001",
    "Value": "200",
    "SourceTimestamp": "2019-01-03 23:40:24"
},
{
    "DisplayName": "Voltage",
    "HwId": "",
    "Address": "400002",
    "Value": "24503",
    "SourceTimestamp": "2019-01-03 23:40:24"
},
...
]
```

I want to convert this array to rows using a stream analytics query containing the **CROSS APPLY GetArrayElements()** but this function requires an array name. Obviously there is no name. Any suggestions?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/stream-analytics-query/getarrayelements-azure-stream-analytics
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/stream-analytics-parsing-json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it needs an array name. `CROSS APPLY GetArrayElements()` is used for nested array.

Example:

```
[{
      "source": "xda",
      "data": 
        [{
            "masterTag": "UNIFY1",
            "speed": 180
        },
        {
            "masterTag": "UNIFY2",
            "speed": 180
        }],
      "EventEnqueuedUtcTime": "2018-07-20T19:28:18.5230000Z",
  },
  {
      "source": "xda",
      "data": [{
            "masterTag": "UNIFY3",
            "speed": 214
        },
        {
            "masterTag": "UNIFY4",
            "speed": 180
        }],
      "EventEnqueuedUtcTime": "2018-07-20T19:28:20.5550000Z",
  }
]
```

You could use below sql to convert it to rows:

```
SELECT 
    jsoninput.source, 
    arrayElement.ArrayValue.masterTag
INTO 
    output
FROM jsoninput
CROSS APPLY GetArrayElements(jsoninput.data) AS arrayElement
```

However ,now the input data you provided is a pure array. If you want to convert this array to rows, just use sql:

```
select jsoninput.* from jsoninput
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. But the problem is there is no array name and I cannot change that. The data is sent via an external system.

Comment: @KevinH So,would you please share what the format of the output you want from you source data?Why you want to use the GetArrayElements method? Please add it into your question?

Comment: @KevinH hi,any updates now? Does my answer helps you?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use GetArrayElements. Just selecting json array as input format is enough. Stream analytics reads each object in the array as a record. Same with line or whitespace separated jain objects, each object is read as a record.

Comment: yes, no need to use GetArrayElements. ASA treats each record as a row from input.